# Testing building Flutter widget throws Exception

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a way to test for building a widget throwing an exception.

I tried this in `testWidgets` but it doesn't recognize the error.

```
expectLater(() async {
  await tester.pumpWidget(...);
}, throwsException);
```

Comment: You probably want to throw on the constructor instead of `build`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only catch exceptions thrown by code invoked by your code.
`build()` is invoked by the Flutter framework and therefore errors land there.

You can register a custom error handler for such exceptions in your test

```
final errorHandled = expectAsync0((){});

FlutterError.onError = (errorDetails) {
  // handle error
  errorHandled();
});
```

This way the test will fail if `errorHandled` isn't called before the test times out.

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/foundation/FlutterError-class.html